# android Web Browser is not working

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a problem with my WebView.

Here's the code:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    EditText editText;
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);



    }

    public void Goo(View view){

        webView.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

here is the code of xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter url"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edittext"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Goo"
        android:text="Go"
        android:id="@+id/but"
        />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />


</LinearLayout>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: when i click on button its nothing happend

Comment: its not open the url.

Comment: What have you inside `editText.getText().toString()`?

Comment: www.google.com have in edittext.

Comment: webview can't recognize  url starting with `www`. Load `http://www.google.com` instead.

Comment: but i want to open url .

Comment: Don't you think that is an url?

Comment: i want to make browser which open the url address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211576/how-to-pass-string-in-webview-url-from-edittext

Answer (score 0):

**try to below code :-**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    EditText editText;
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    }

    public void Goo(View view){
        String url = editText.getText().toString();
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

add Following permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: com.example.xtylishmalik.ebrowser W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 18504